# How to Recompile React-native Project in Terminal?

Tags: compilation, react-native

I have installed a third party library and now I have to recompile my code !

Please tell me how to do that. 
and what is the use of React packager ?

Answer (score 2):

Delete your build files.

for iOS `projectroot/ios/build` and for Android `projectroot/android/projectname/build`

Comment: http://nativebase.io/docs/v0.5.0/getting-started 
I want to add this library and I have done as instructed in "getting started" but it is showing error in importing from 'native-base'.

Comment: you did `rnpm link`? By the way what is the error message post it here.